# Vector size() returning seemingly random large integers

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I am working on a program for homework and ran into a strange problem. When trying to get the size of a 2D vector using the size() function, I get seemingly random large integers which stop my program from running. I need the size to access elements in the vector.

My header file:

```
#ifndef _MATRIX_H
#define _MATRIX_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix {

    private:
        //int dimension;

        std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix;

    public:

        Matrix();

        Matrix(std::vector< std::vector<int> >);

        void print();

        Matrix operator-(Matrix operand);

};

#endif
```

My implementation file:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Default constructor
Matrix::Matrix() {

}

// Parameterized constructor
Matrix::Matrix(std::vector< std::vector<int> >) {

}

void Matrix::print() {
    std::cout << "Size of matrix in print() " << matrix.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.size(); j++) {
                std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

Matrix Matrix::operator-(Matrix operand) {

    Matrix difference;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > diffMatrix;

    diffMatrix.resize(matrix.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++ ) {
        diffMatrix[i].resize(matrix.size());
    }

    difference.matrix = diffMatrix;
    if (operand.matrix.size() == matrix.size()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < operand.matrix.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < operand.matrix.size(); j++) {
                difference.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - operand.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }   
    } 
}
```

and my main.cpp file:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector< vector<int> > testMatrixOne(4);
    vector< vector<int> > testMatrixTwo(4);

    // Creating a test matrix
    testMatrixOne = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    testMatrixTwo = {{5,6},{7,8}};

    // Create Matrix object
    Matrix matrixOne(testMatrixOne);
    Matrix matrixTwo(testMatrixTwo);

    // Create Matrix to store difference
    Matrix diff;
    diff = matrixOne - matrixTwo;
    diff.print();


    return 0;
}
```

I have simplified my code and hardcoded in two matrices. When running the program, the size() will return a very large integer. I have spent several hours searching online but couldn't find out what's the cause of this. Why is the size() function doing this?

Comment: The constructors of `Matrix` never initialize `dimension`

Comment: I am not using the dimension variable at the moment, the size() function is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: `Matrix::Matrix(std::vector< std::vector<int> >)` leaves the matrix empty, and that's the constructor you use.

Comment: You also have several places in this code that should b using using `j < matrix[i].size()` for the termination limit, not `j < matrix.size()`.

Comment: @Adam the entire code assumes square matrices , that in itself shouldn't lead to the problem

Comment: @MattMcNabb it just screams bad practice. This is homework, so presumably learning bad habits should be avoided. The whole point of this style of 2D array is to have different-length arrays on the 2nd dimension.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Even after initializing the matrix in the constructor, I get the same thing. And the homework problem allows us to assume square matrices.

Comment: @MattMcNabb if you're referring to there being no established return result of the `operator -` member, it may not be as immediately noticed as you think =P. Apparently the compiler warning wasn't sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, `operator-` is missing a `return` -- didn't your compiler complain?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz For some reason my compiler did not complain about that...

Comment: @Skynet when learning always use `-Wall` and learn to code so you don't get any warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is unfortunately that:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator-(Matrix operand) {
```

never returns a value. This causes undefined behaviour, and the symptoms you saw were the result of the `-` appearing to return garbage.

At the end of the function, you meant to have:

```
    return difference;
}
```

The C++ standard doesn't require compilers to warn about this, but it's still nice if they do warn. My version of g++ doesn't (even with -Wall), however adding the flag `-Wreturn-type` does produce a warning. IDK why this isn't part of `-Wall`, at least for simple cases like this.

Comment: This fixed it! I'm still new to C++, could you explain what -Wall is?

Comment: -Wall is a compiler switch to enable "all" warnings (in reality: a common set of warnings). g++ and clang use the same syntax for compiler warnings. Check your compiler documentation for more info about enabling warnings.

Comment: [Further reading about g++ warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402178/omitting-return-statement-in-c)