# RecursiveASTVisitor not visiting clang::VarDecl

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

I have the following c code `test1.c`:

```c
double multiply(double x, double y) {
    return x * y * y;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double a;

    int b;

    float d;

    double x = 3.0;
    double y = 5.0;

    double z = multiply(x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get the RecursiveASTVisitor to visit variable declarations (clang::VarDecl) by implementing `bool VistVarDecl(clang::VarDecl *vardecl)`. However, the `clang::VarDecl` nodes are never visited even though I've managed to visit all the other nodes in the AST though. Moreover, using `clang-query` on `test1.c` I *can* match `varDecl`.

My RecursiveASTVistor is as follows:

```cpp
struct MyASTVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVistor<MyASTVisitor> {

  bool VistVarDecl(clang::VarDecl *vardecl) {
     llvm::outs() << "Found a VarDecl";
  };

  bool VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *decl) {
     llvm::outs() << "Found a FunctionDecl";
  };

  // other functions implemented similarly just to see if it visits properly
  bool VisitParmVarmDecl(clang::ParmVarDecl *paramvardecl);
  bool VisitCallExpr(clang::CallExpr *callexpr);
  bool VisitImplicitCastExpr(clang::ImplicitCastExpr *castexpr);
  bool VisitBinaryOperator(clang::BinaryOperator *bo);
  bool VisitDeclStmt(clang::DeclStmt *declstmt);
  bool VisitDeclRefExpr(clang::DeclRefExpr *declrefexpr);
  bool VisitFloatingLiteral(clang::FloatingLiteral *floatliteral);
};

struct MyASTConsumer : public clang::ASTConsumer {

  bool HandleTopLevelDecl(clang::DeclGroupRef DR) override {
    for (clang::DeclGroupRef::iterator b = DR.begin(), e = DR.end(); b != e; ++b) {
        Visitor.TraverseDecl(*b);
     }
     return true;
  }
private: 
  MyASTVisitor Visitor;
};
```

Does anyone know the `clang::VarDecl` nodes are the only nodes that aren't visited by the `RecursiveASTVisitor` but are matched by `clang-query`?

The AST dump from clang is given below:

```sh
TranslationUnitDecl 0x7fba2300ce08 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fba2300d6a0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __int128_t '__int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x7fba2300d3a0 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fba2300d710 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x7fba2300d3c0 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fba2300da18 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __NSConstantString 'struct __NSConstantString_tag'
| `-RecordType 0x7fba2300d7f0 'struct __NSConstantString_tag'
|   `-Record 0x7fba2300d768 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fba2300dab0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_ms_va_list 'char *'
| `-PointerType 0x7fba2300da70 'char *'
|   `-BuiltinType 0x7fba2300cea0 'char'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fba2300dda8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_va_list 'struct __va_list_tag [1]'
| `-ConstantArrayType 0x7fba2300dd50 'struct __va_list_tag [1]' 1
|   `-RecordType 0x7fba2300db90 'struct __va_list_tag'
|     `-Record 0x7fba2300db08 '__va_list_tag'
|-FunctionDecl 0x7fba22829370 <test4.c:2:1, line:4:1> line:2:8 used multiply 'double (double, double)'
| |-ParmVarDecl 0x7fba22829218 <col:17, col:24> col:24 used x 'double'
| |-ParmVarDecl 0x7fba22829298 <col:27, col:34> col:34 used y 'double'
| `-CompoundStmt 0x7fba22829560 <col:37, line:4:1>
|   `-ReturnStmt 0x7fba22829550 <line:3:2, col:17>
|     `-BinaryOperator 0x7fba22829530 <col:9, col:17> 'double' '*'
|       |-BinaryOperator 0x7fba228294d8 <col:9, col:13> 'double' '*'
|       | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fba228294a8 <col:9> 'double' <LValueToRValue>
|       | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fba22829468 <col:9> 'double' lvalue ParmVar 0x7fba22829218 'x' 'double'
|       | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fba228294c0 <col:13> 'double' <LValueToRValue>
|       |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fba22829488 <col:13> 'double' lvalue ParmVar 0x7fba22829298 'y' 'double'
|       `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fba22829518 <col:17> 'double' <LValueToRValue>
|         `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fba228294f8 <col:17> 'double' lvalue ParmVar 0x7fba22829298 'y' 'double'
`-FunctionDecl 0x7fba228297d0 <line:6:1, line:22:1> line:6:5 main 'int (int, const char **)'
  |-ParmVarDecl 0x7fba22829590 <col:10, col:14> col:14 argc 'int'
  |-ParmVarDecl 0x7fba228296b0 <col:20, col:37> col:32 argv 'const char **':'const char **'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x7fba22829da8 <line:7:1, line:22:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x7fba22829928 <line:10:2, col:10>
    | `-VarDecl 0x7fba228298c0 <col:2, col:9> col:9 a 'double'
    |-DeclStmt 0x7fba228299c0 <line:12:2, col:7>
    | `-VarDecl 0x7fba22829958 <col:2, col:6> col:6 b 'int'
    |-DeclStmt 0x7fba22829a58 <line:14:2, col:9>
    | `-VarDecl 0x7fba228299f0 <col:2, col:8> col:8 d 'float'
    |-DeclStmt 0x7fba22829b10 <line:16:2, col:16>
    | `-VarDecl 0x7fba22829a88 <col:2, col:13> col:9 used x 'double' cinit
    |   `-FloatingLiteral 0x7fba22829af0 <col:13> 'double' 3.000000e+00
    |-DeclStmt 0x7fba22829bc8 <line:17:2, col:16>
    | `-VarDecl 0x7fba22829b40 <col:2, col:13> col:9 used y 'double' cinit
    |   `-FloatingLiteral 0x7fba22829ba8 <col:13> 'double' 5.000000e+00
    |-DeclStmt 0x7fba22829d60 <line:19:2, col:26>
    | `-VarDecl 0x7fba22829bf8 <col:2, col:25> col:9 z 'double' cinit
    |   `-CallExpr 0x7fba22829d00 <col:13, col:25> 'double'
    |     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fba22829ce8 <col:13> 'double (*)(double, double)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
    |     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fba22829c60 <col:13> 'double (double, double)' Function 0x7fba22829370 'multiply' 'double (double, double)'
    |     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fba22829d30 <col:22> 'double' <LValueToRValue>
    |     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fba22829c80 <col:22> 'double' lvalue Var 0x7fba22829a88 'x' 'double'
    |     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fba22829d48 <col:24> 'double' <LValueToRValue>
    |       `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fba22829ca0 <col:24> 'double' lvalue Var 0x7fba22829b40 'y' 'double'
    `-ReturnStmt 0x7fba22829d98 <line:21:2, col:9>
      `-IntegerLiteral 0x7fba22829d78 <col:9> 'int' 0
```

Comment: You'll get a better chance of getting the answer if you also include the code of the visitor :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @AlexDenisov.

Comment: Your `Visit*Decl` methods should return `true` explicitly. Without it, you are entering an area of undefined behavior and your program can do many unexpected things. In this specific case, I assume your program behaves as if you return `false`, which tells the ASTVisitor to stop traversing immediately. Try adding explicit `return true` to the end of each `Visit*` function.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the problem here almost certainly is the failure to explicitly `return true` at the end of the `Visit` methods:

```
  bool VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *decl) {
     llvm::outs() << "Found a FunctionDecl";
  };
```

[Omitting the `return` causes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402178/omitting-return-statement-in-c).  In practice, whatever is in the register used to convey return values may be used as-is, so if that register happens to contain 0, then `false` is effectively returned.

`VisitFunctionDecl` is called before its body is visited, and if `false` is returned, then the entire traversal is aborted, so it never gets to the `VarDecl` nodes.

Quoting the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html#details):

> Returning false from one of these overridden functions will abort the entire traversal.